# How to use react-widgets-webpack with extract-text-webpack-plugin for Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack-2, extracttextwebpackplugin

When I attempt to follow the [instructions](https://github.com/PapaiaKrica/react-widgets-webpack#extract-text-webpack-plugin) for using react-widgets-webpack with
 extract-text-webpack-plugin and Webpack 2, I get the following error:

> ERROR in
>   ./~/react-widgets-webpack/index.loader.js!./react-widgets.config.js
>   Module build failed: Error: Breaking change: extract now only takes a
>   single argument. Either an options object *or* the loader(s). Example:
>   if your old code looked like this:
>       ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
>
> You would change it to:
>       ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })

Changing to

```
styleLoader: require('extract-text-webpack-plugin').extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: 'css-loader!less-loader'
    })
```

gives the following error:

> ERROR in
>   ./~/react-widgets-webpack/index.loader.js!./react-widgets.config.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object]' in
>   '/Users/pbirmingham/Development/FLA/forks/flash/flash'

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const globalizePlugin = require('globalize-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            'react-widgets-webpack!./react-widgets.config.js',
            'bootstrap-loader',
            './js/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: './public/',
        filename: 'js/bundle-[hash].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader'},
            {test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader'},
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: "url-loader?name=[name].[hash].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif)$/, use: "file-loader?name=[name].[hash].[ext]"},
            {test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'css/main.[contenthash].css'}),
        new globalizePlugin({
            production: false,
            developmentLocale: "en",
            supportedLocales: ["en"],
            output: "globalize-compiled-data-[locale].[hash].js"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template/index.ejs',
            chunks: ['app']
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Set in package.json `"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~0.8.0"` then define ExtractTextPlugin loader like `loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!less')`